# How to Add/Edit keyboard shortcuts in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

Anybody know how to Add/edit a Windows 8 keyboard shortcut?

I used <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> to change volume in Windows 7, but they are gone when I updated to Windows 8. Is there any way I could get them back?

I searched the internet and it seems as though everybody is writing books about new shortcuts in Windows 8, yet nobody knows how to customize them.

Comment: May we know your computer model? I take it nothing changed in the BIOS.

Comment: Asus K40ij.
Nothing changed in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can do custom short-cuts for FN keys unless the driver software from your computer vendor allows you to do so. Windows may not even see the key press of FN.

If Fn+F11, etc. used to work in Windows 7, then it means the hotkey driver is not compatible with Windows 8 or gets uninstalled during the upgrade. You'll need to find the Windows 8 version.